# Logging tf.variable during custom training loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, logging

I have written a custom training loop for a TD(Lambda) in TensorFlow, and I want to create a log that stores some of the variables that are computed during each epoch.

In numpy, I would write something like
list.append(variable_that_I_want_to_save)
at the end of every epoch

But in tf eager execution it is not possible.

How can I save the values that a tf.Variable in a tf.function takes during iterations?

Thanks a lot in advance for your efforts to reply - I imagine that this must be a quite trivial thing.

PS:
I should add that the training occurs in a class, so tf.concat does not solve the issue because I am unable to repeatedly assign the concatenated tensor to an instance variable of the training_loop class...

Here is pseudo code of the what I do:

```
class Trainer:
   def __init__(self, model):
      self.model = model

   def train(xs,ys,lambda):
      for x,y in zip(xs,ys):
         learn(x,y,lambda)

   def learn(x,y,lambda):
      err = y - self.model(x)
      model.apply_weights( grad(err) * self.custom_alpha( self.model.weights )

   def custom_optimizer(  weights ):
      x = some operations with weights 
      alpha = some operation with x
      return alpha
```

I can't share more specific because of an NDA, but what i want to log is the values that x takes

Comment: Please add the code of the custom training loop

Comment: Hi, 
Essentially, the training class looks like this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could something like this work for you?
I have added a property to the class that it will store the log.

```
class Trainer:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        self.log_variable = []

    def train(self, xs, ys, lambda):
        for x,y in zip(xs,ys):
            v = learn(x,y,lambda)
            self.log_variable.append(v.numpy())

    @tf.function
    def learn(self, x, y, lambda):
        err = y - self.model(x)
        model.apply_weights( grad(err) * self.custom_alpha( self.model.weights )
        return variable_that_I_want_to_save

    def custom_optimizer( weights ):
        x = some operations with weights 
        alpha = some operation with x
        return alpha

    def get_log(self):
        return self.log_variable

trainer = Trainer(model)
trainer.train(xs, ys, lambda)
log = trainer.log_variable()
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply and sorry for the delayed answer. 
I also had something like this in mind, but it seems that the .numpy() attribute is not available in eager execution.

I get this error message:

AttributeError: in user code:

learn_sequence  *
        alphas, mask = self.optimizer.alpha(
py:309 alpha  *
        self.norm_trace.append( norms.numpy() )

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: Instead of .numpy(), you can try tf.make_ndarray(tf.make_tensor_proto(norms)) https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_ndarray It creates a numpy ndarray from a tensor.

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow are you using?

Comment: Thanks!

I now get the error:

TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, got a tensor instead (because norms are indeed a tensor).

and if I remove the tf.make_tensor_proto, I get:

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape'

I am working in tensorflow 2.2.0!

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: PS. it might be helpful to know that the learn() function is wrapped in a @tf.function decorator

Comment: Oh! that's why you couldn't use .numpy(). When you use the @tf.function, TensorFlow uses graph execution instead of eager execution (similarly to tf1). In order to get the variable in EagerTensor, you have to return the variables from the learn function and then you can save it as NumPy. Have a look at the code in the answer, I have edited it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I have been pondering on.. there is no way to tell the eager tensor to save / screenshot / return its state every N computation? It seems like something that would be so useful for anyone studying the development of the training process? I saw that callbacks/checkpoints can do this, but I haven't found a simple guide on how those can be inserted in custom training loops...? Thanks again for your help, if the answer to these questions are non-trivial, I will mark your post as solving answer.

Comment: Did you try the code I added? I think it should work for you. Yes, checkpoints could work too altho in your case where you just want to save one variable, I would do it as I did in the answer code. Here it is a reference on how to use the checkpoints in custom training loops [[1]](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#manual_checkpointing), it may help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! The code you put worked!